# Finding most frequent occurrence in list of floats

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict

L = [1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.1,5.1]
d = defaultdict(float)
for i in L:
    d[i] += 1
most_frequent = sorted(Counter(L).most_common(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[0]
print(most_frequent)
```

outputs: (1.0, 1)

The code *should* output "Your mode(s) are 1.0, 2.0, 5.1" in this scenario. However I run the program and get only the first mode, and not all modes included

How do I fix this?

Comment: Particularly 'unhashable type' can be solved by using `L` instead of `c` when passing to `Counter`: `... Counter(L).most_common(), ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `Counter`'s `most_common` function's second argument, like this

```
print([num for num, count in Counter(L).most_common(3)])
```

**Output**

```
[1.0, 2.0, 5.1]
```

Comment: Wont that only print 3 when I tell it to? I want it to print as many as the user inputs. Sorry should of specified that

Comment: This also automatically shows the top 3 so if the list is 3,3,2,1 it'll print 3.0, 1.0, 2.0 not just 3.0

Comment: @Moose Could you please explain your problem clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?  It could be faster, but it's pretty readable:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import collections

list_ = [1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.1,5.1]

frequencies = collections.Counter(list_)

reverse_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key, value in frequencies.items():
    reverse_dict[value].append(key)

maximum_count = max(reverse_dict)

print('Your modes are {}'.format((reverse_dict[maximum_count]), ))
```